# Show that $x^2+y^2$ is constant for all values of $\theta$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $x=3\sin \theta-2 \cos \theta$ and $y=3\cos \theta+2 \sin \theta$

i)Find the value of the acute angle $\theta$ for which $x=y$

ii)Show that $x^2+y^2$ is constant for all values of $\theta$.

My attempt,

$3\sin \theta-2 \cos \theta=3 \cos \theta+2 \sin \theta$

$\sin \theta=5 \cos \theta$

$\sin \theta-5 \cos \theta=0$

$\tan \theta-5=0$

$\theta=78.7$

How to solve question ii?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to the theorem. Can you explain more about it? Thannks

Comment: $a=3,d=\sin\theta, b=2,c=\cos\theta$ in the link

Comment: You can notice that this is just [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Two_dimensions) of the vector $(3,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $x^2+y^2 = 9(\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2\theta)+4(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) = ....$

Comment: Yea. I got $13(\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta$). Then? How should I continue?

Comment: what is $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta$

Comment: It's 1. So I will get 13.

Comment: Yes, you will. Good job !